# How to lock actual horizontal position of dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using MySqlConnector and execute query to provide data source for `dataGridView`.

`SELECT` query returns many rows and it is refreshing every 10 seconds. I want to "lock scroll" when it is updating.

When I scroll down in UI it goes back to the top after update data source. I want it in this same position after update.

It has refresh void in another thread and bindingsource is assigned as data source in another void which is executed on startup of the form.

```
void refresh()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        for (;;)
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            
            SafeUpdate(() => bindingSource1.DataSource = ds);
            
            conn.Close();
        }
    }



void startup()
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
        MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10000); for (;;)`  Yikes! Use a WinForm's Timer.

Comment: When you state that the… _”SELECT query returns many rows and it is refreshing every 10 seconds.”_ …  this is not true. When the `refresh` method is called, the UI will freeze for 10 seconds, then will start an infinite loop that NEVER stops executing the code in the unbounded `for` loop… `for (;;)`. Once this method is called, the UI is going to become unresponsive. You need to re-think this approach.

Comment: Your `refresh` method is not refreshing anything at all - it is creating and filling a *new* `DataTable` and setting it as the DataSource.  Make the DBAdapter a persistent one for a proper refresh.  Examples are plentiful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current code works (which I question) and you can scroll the rows in the grid, then, If you want to display the current “displayed” cells in the grids viewable area after the grids data source has be “refreshed”, then you may want to grab the grids `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` “before” refreshing the grids data source… then “after” the grids data source has been “refreshed,” set the grids `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` to the previously grabbed index. Something like…

```
int curIndex = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
Refresh grids data source();
if (curIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count) {
  dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = curIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also works for vertical if i change `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` to `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex`.